# Can I use Write-SqlTableData

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use this cmdlet: Write-SqlTableData in sql server 2012 and below?
Its a new thing added to sql 2016. I have some powershell output that needs to be stored into MS SQL 2012 database.

Let me know

Comment: The cmdlet doesn't do anything that's specific to SQL Server 2016, so I don't see why not. You don't need to have SQL Server 2016 installed to use those cmdlets; installing the latest version of Management Studio and importing the `SqlServer` module is sufficient.

Comment: @JeroenMostert SSMS 2016 isn't even required anymore and it's not shipped with SSMS 2017 - the `sqlserver` module is now hosted in the PowerShell Gallery.

Comment: @alroc: good to know! I have a few scenarios where this will come in particularly handy. In that case, `Install-Module SqlServer` is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought it only works in SQL 2016 but I realized that you either need to import the module: SqlServer or Install-Module SqlServer. Either 2 ways, it should work. Thanks for your help guys. Powershell is taking over the world.